# Applying function to Pandas with GroupBy along direction of the grouping variable

Tags: pandas, grouping

I have a cohort of N people and I computed a correlation matrix of some quantities (q1_score,...q5_score)

```
    df.groupby('participant_id').corr()
    Out[130]: 
                                q1_score    q2_score   q3_score  q4_score   q5_score
    participant_id                                                                      
    11.0           q1_score     1.000000   -0.748887  -0.546893  -0.213635  -0.231169
                   q2_score    -0.748887    1.000000   0.639649   0.324976   0.335596
                   q3_score    -0.546893    0.639649   1.000000   0.154539   0.151233
                   q4_score    -0.213635    0.324976   0.154539   1.000000   0.998752              
                   q5_score    -0.231169    0.335596   0.151233   0.998752   1.000000
    14.0           q1_score     1.000000   -0.668781  -0.124614  -0.352075  -0.244251
                   q2_score    -0.668781    1.000000  -0.175432   0.360183   0.184585
                   q3_score    -0.124614   -0.175432   1.000000  -0.137993  -0.125115
                   q4_score    -0.352075    0.360183  -0.137993   1.000000   0.968564
                   q5_score    -0.244251    0.184585  -0.125115   0.968564   1.000000
    17.0           q1_score     1.000000   -0.799223  -0.814424  -0.790587  -0.777318
                   q2_score    -0.799223    1.000000   0.787238   0.658524   0.640786
                   q3_score    -0.814424    0.787238   1.000000   0.702570   0.701440
                   q4_score    -0.790587    0.658524   0.702570   1.000000   0.998996
                   q5_score    -0.777318    0.640786   0.701440   0.998996   1.000000
    18.0           q1_score     1.000000   -0.595545  -0.617691  -0.472409  -0.477523
                   q2_score    -0.595545    1.000000   0.386705   0.148761   0.115068
                   q3_score    -0.617691    0.386705   1.000000   0.806637   0.782345
                   q4_score    -0.472409    0.148761   0.806637   1.000000   0.982617
                   q5_score    -0.477523    0.115068   0.782345   0.982617   1.000000
```

I need to compute the median values of the correlations of all participants? What I mean: I need to take corr. between the item J and item K for all participants and find their median value.

I am sure it is a one line of code, but I'm struggling to realise (still learning pandas by examples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack your data, and do another groupby:

```
df.groupby('participant_id').corr().stack().groupby(level = [1,2]).median()
```

Edit: Actually, you don't need to stack if you don't want to:

```
df.groupby('participant_id').corr().groupby(level = [1]).median()
```

works too.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you want the average mean of each participant across all questions:

```
df.where(df != 1).mean(axis=1).mean(level=0)
```

Let's get rid of correlations with same question with `where`, then get the mean for all questions by participant_id with direction of `axis=1`, then get the participant_id mean `level=0`.

Output:

```
participant_id
11.0    0.086416
14.0   -0.031493
17.0    0.130800
18.0    0.105896
dtype: float64
```

## Edit: I used mean instead of median, we can so do the same logic with median.

```
df.where(df != 1).median(axis=1).median(level=0)
```

Comment: thanks but it didn't work for me. I could not reproduce your result, there is something wrong with `where(df != 1)`